# nvidia-driver-435.21 Lubuntu 19.10 black login screen but ssh works

Tags: boot, login-screen

Hardware:

new computer, Ryzen threadripper 2950x, 128 GB DDR4, running Lubuntu 19.10, NVIDIA Quadro P400

System:

single boot Lubuntu 19.10 fresh install

Problem:

On boot/reboot the system starts up, but graphical login does not start up. The machine is operating as I can SSH into it, etc.

Diagnostics:

```
xxx@pxe:~$ nvidia-smi
Tue Feb 11 19:28:16 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P400         Off  | 00000000:42:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 34%   34C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    168MiB /  1997MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1734      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           165MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
xxx@pxe:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:40/0000:40:03.1/0000:42:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001CB3sv000010DEsd000011BEbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP107GL [Quadro P400]
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

xxx@pxe:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
42:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL [Quadro P400] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL [Quadro P400]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
jaca@pxe:~$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA
42:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL [Quadro P400] [10de:1cb3] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
xxx@pxe:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a probably related problem with Ubuntu 19.10 on a new system with a Geforce RTX 2060, only that it was a login loop (I saw the graphical login but it will return to it when entering the password).

In the end what it made it work was uninstalling/reinstalling gdm3 from the root prompt.

I don't keep the link for the post that gave me the solution (never posted myself since somebody asked the same problem previously), but you may try also looking for 'login loop 19.10', maybe the solutions are similar.

Also typical solutions for avoiding graphical issues on startup include adding `nomodeset` between the quotes in line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` in file `/etc/default/grub`.

Hope it helps at least a bit but **please confirm possible solutions with others before proceeding since I am not that expert!**